# An attempt to create a project using the tutorial example of Spring Android. Does anyone know how to solve?

Tags: android, spring

I did everything I had in the instructions.

```
dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE'
compile 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.3.2'
```

}

```
Error:Could not download artifact 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:1.0.1.RELEASE:spring-android-rest-template.jar'
```

Answer (score 0):

edited, did not work for me try this one, it's from the official docs
[check here for more info](http://projects.spring.io/spring-android/)

```
dependencies {
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
}

repositories {
    maven {
         url 'http://repo.spring.io/milestone'
    }
}
```

Comment: Adding some description of why this is a good solution would be helpful.

Comment: Replaces the line you asked, but gave the same error above.